# How to use completion-style in execute-extended-command in slime-mode?

Tags: completion

I'm trying to use fuzzy completion all over emacs.

I added this line to my `init.el` file `(setq completion-styles '(initials flex))` which seems to have worked for opening project files.

It works on `M-x` however upon entering `slime-mode` it for some reason no longer works on `execute-extended-command` AKA `M-x` it still only completes until the hyphen and any characters that may appear after the hyphen are not used to complete the whole command name.

How can I accomplish fuzzy completion in the `execute-extended-command` buffer on `slime-mode`?

For example typing `M-x` and searching for the string `install` would show only `install-bridge` but I would like to get in the autocomplete list of options `package-install` as well.

I don't want to have to type `*`, because the point is to be able to explore and it's quite inconvenient to type `*` every time twice for it to be `*install*`.

Comment: Could you show a step-by-step recipe to reproduce the problem, starting from `emacs -Q` (no init file)?

Comment: Sure, will update the post now. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried reversing the order: `(flex initials)`?

Comment: @Drew thanks for the reply. But shouldn't it work anyways if there are no suggestions with initials? I just realized it was actually working when not using `slime`, so it seems it's `slime-mode` causing the issue. Any ideas why that may be?

Comment: 1. How do you know there's no match for initials? 2. Check `completion-category-overrides`  in `slime-mode`. 3. Try debugging completion functions, such as `M-x debug-on-entry completion-try-completion`.